# Is there a way to get and set a control variable during the aggregation process?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have simplified my specific problem so it's easier to understand, but the data I want to aggregate are user events on a video player page, and it looks like this:

```
{_id:"5963796a46d12ed9891f8c80",eventName:"Click Freature 1",creation:1499691279492},
{_id:"59637a5a46d12ed9891f8e0d",eventName:"Video Play",creation:1499691608106},
{_id:"59637a9546d12ed9891f8e90",eventName:"Click Freature 1",creation:1499691664633},
{_id:"59637c0f46d12ed9891f9146",eventName:"Video Pause",creation:1499692055335}
```

So the events are consistent and on a chronological order. Let's say I want to count the number of times the user clicked feature 1, but only when the video is playing.

I believe I would have to have some control variable like "isVideoPlaying", that is set to true when a "Video Play" event comes up, and is set to false in case of a "Video Pause", and then add the "Click Feature 1" events to the count only when it's set to ture.

Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: better stream and do at application side

Comment: I think it's tricky to do that in my case, I have a plan B but I'm really curious to know if this sort of thing is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get and set a control variable during the
>   aggregation process?

No, there is no way to keep track of previous/next when aggregation pipeline is executed.

The idea is to convert the events for each event into its own time array values.

You have two options.

Breakdown

```
Video Play :             [1,5,7]
Video Pause :            [3,6,10]
Features :               [2,4,8,9]

Play-Features :            2           8,9          
Video play-pause pair  : [1,3],[5,6],[7,10]
Pause-Features :          4             
Video pause-play pair :  [3,5],[6,7],[10,-]
```

Expected Output

```
{count:3}
```

**First Option:** (You do all the work in aggregation pipeline )

Use extra stages to transform the documents into the events-array structure.

Consider below documents

```
db.collection.insertMany([
{eventName:"Video Play",creation:1},
{eventName:"Click Features 1",creation:2},
{eventName:"Video Pause",creation:3}, 
{eventName:"Click Features 1",creation:4},
{eventName:"Video Play",creation:5},
{eventName:"Video Pause",creation:6},
{eventName:"Video Play",creation:7},
{eventName:"Click Features 1",creation:8},
{eventName:"Click Features 1",creation:9},
{eventName:"Video Pause",creation:10}
]);
```

You can use below aggregation

The aggregation below uses two `$group` stage to convert the events into its time array followed by `$project` stage to project (`$let`) each event creations array  into a variables.

For logic explanation inside `$let` see the option 2

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "eventName": 1,
      "creation": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$eventName",
      "creations": {
        "$push": "$creation"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "null",
      "events": {
        "$push": {
          "eventName": "$_id",
          "creations": "$creations"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "count": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "video_play_events": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$events.creations",
                {
                  "$indexOfArray": [
                    "$events.eventName",
                    "Video Play"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "click_features_event": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$events.creations",
                {
                  "$indexOfArray": [
                    "$events.eventName",
                    "Click Features 1"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "video_pause_events": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$events.creations",
                {
                  "$indexOfArray": [
                    "$events.eventName",
                    "Video Pause"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "in": {*}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

*You have events creations array for each event at this point. Insert below aggregation code and replace `$video_play_events` with `$$video_play_events` and so on to access variables from `$let` stage.

**Second Option:** ( You save events in its own array )

```
db.collection.insert([
  {
    "video_play_events": [
      1,
      5,
      7
    ],
    "click_features_event": [
      2,
      4,
      8,
      9
    ],
    "video_pause_events": [
      3,
      6,
      10
    ]
  }
])
```

You can manage the array growth by adding extra field "count" to limit the no of events you can store in one document.

You can have multiple document for a chosen time slice.

This will simplify the aggregation to below.

The aggregation below iterates over `video_play_events` and filters all the click features for each play and pause pair (`pl` and `pu`).

`$size` to count no of features elements between each play and pause pair followed by `$map` + `$sum` to count all features event for all play pause pairs.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$range": [
                0,
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    {
                      "$size": "$video_play_events"
                    },
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "as": "z",
            "in": {
              "$let": {
                "vars": {
                  "pl": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$video_pause_events",
                      "$$z"
                    ]
                  },
                  "pu": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$video_play_events",
                      {
                        "$add": [
                          1,
                          "$$z"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "in": {
                  "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$click_features_event",
                      "as": "fe",
                      "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                          {
                            "$gt": [
                              "$$fe",
                              "$$pl"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "$lt": [
                              "$$fe",
                              "$$pu"
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Notes:

You run the risk of hitting 16 MB document limit based on no of documents you are trying to aggregate in both cases.

You can use async module to run parallel queries with appropriate filters to contain the data you are aggregating followed by client side logic to count all the parts.

Comment: Thank you very much! So unfortunately I was trying to test this but then I realized I'm stuck with mongodb 5.2 and $indexOfArray is not gonna work. So now I think I'm probably gonna have to either redesign what gets sent from the client, or I have to use mapReduce instead.